# How does permuting rows of a positive matrix affect the eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume I have a positive matrix (strictly positive entries) $A$. By perron-frobenius theorem, spectral radius (positive by definition) is indeed the largest eigenvalue (called perron root) with the corresponding eigenvector (called perron vector) having strictly positive entries. If I permute the rows of $A$, say by multiplying with $P$, a permutation matrix, how is the perron vector of $B=PA$ related to that of $A$.